# Use Slick Slider to just rotate the class, No of slides = slidesToShow

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I have 3 slider items and I want to show all 3 and use slick slider to just rotate the "slick-active" class so I can show hide the text through this class using css.
I know I can do it with custom js but is it possible within slick slider ?

```
$('.slider_nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    centerMode: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true
  });
```

Comment: why your not reading slick slider documentation & events. please check https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @HardikGodhani I couldnt find anything in example and docs, thats why I posted here.

Comment: you can `addClass` in `init` events. if possible to add demo in codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: In slick slider `.slick-current` class add on current slide so you can use this class to show your text

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use an external library for this case as long as you can do it manually with jQuery as you're already using it!

I've made a simple example for you to give you an idea and you can continue with your design/layout and animation.

```js
$('.item').on('click', function() {
  $('.item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 33%;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.item.active {
  background: #E5863D;
}
.item.active p {
  display: block;
}

.item p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item active">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <p>Text for item #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <p>Text for item #2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <p>Text for item #3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I mentioned I am asking for solution within slick slider.